# Angular module dependency injection not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So I am having troubles with managing dependencies for my node app. The structure is the following

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myController', 'myFactory', 'rzModule', 'chart.js', 'myService', 'selector']);
```

myController.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js', 'rzModule', 'selector']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, myFactory, mySecondService){ ... }]);
```

myFactory.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', function($http, $rootScope){ ... });
```

myService.js

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function($http){...});
```

Above structure works, the app runs as expected. However I don't think what I am doing in myController.js is correct, because I now want to add another dependency and I can't figure out how to do so without the app crashing.

**Question 1:** In above myController.js, I think I am creating a new module instead of reusing the one from app.js, is that correct? If so, moving the 3 dependencies inline like the following results in "myController is not available":

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myController',['chart.js', 'rzModule', 'selector', function(...)
```

Why does this not work? According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) it should.

**Question 2:** I want to add [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) to the myController. The instructions say I should add `'angularMoment'` as dependency to the app.js, and then `'moment'` to the controller dependencies. If I do so and add `'moment'` inline like in Question 1, I am getting again the "myController is not available" error.

Comment: `app.controller('myController',['chart.js', 'rzMo....` is the way to proceed, What is the sequence of the files?

Comment: @Satpal that was my guess, but as mentioned, it results in the controller not being available.

Comment: why do you use `myController` inside your `angular.module('myApp'` decleration?

Comment: @ffritz that's because you need to remove `'myController'` from here `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myController'`

Comment: So services/factories should not be included in the app dependencies?

Comment: @ffritz correct, as they're services/factories and not modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So before answering your questions 
quick thing as you proceed with angularjs, modules need to be injected into the app not into the controller, so any module to be included need to be injected in the app.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [<all modules comma separated>]);
```

Similarly controller can have all those dependencies which are either linked to the `myApp`(like services, factories and others) and those services which are defined in modules which are injected into `myApp`

you cannot inject controllers, services in myApp only modules can be injected there

**Question1**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js', 'rzModule', 'selector']);
app.controller('myController', function(...)
```

this shold work and using this it not meant you are creating any new app

**Question2**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularMoment']);
app.controller('myController', ['moment', function(...)
```

like this you can use moment object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So regarding `angularMoment`, it needs to be injected both in app.js and in the respective controller using it? Same goes for any other module used by a controller/service? I adapted my code according to this, and now have the issue that `myService` is undefined in `myController`, and injecting it right next to `moment` doesn't fix it.

Comment: --Update: Seems like when inline injecting a service, you also have to inject all others like `$scope` and `$http`. Works now!

Answer (score 1):

As Satpal has said

```
app.controller('myController',['chart.js', 'rzMo
```

Is the way to go, or a cleaner way to write this would be to do something like this.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController');

myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'myFactory', 'mySecondService']

function myController($scope, $http, $rootScope, myFactory, mySecondService){}
```

The reason `myController` is not available with the fixes is that it's now you're not overwriting the main application module and it's looking for a module called `myController` which can't be found (as it's a controller and not a module). So remove `'myController'` from `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myController'`

I suggest for you to take a look at [John Papa's Style Guide for AngularJS](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) it can be helpful for writing clean code.

Comment: Thanks, however first I think the injection should look like this: `myController.$inject = ['$scope' ...]`. Second this leads to `The controller with the name 'myController' is not registered.` for me.

Comment: @ffritz You're right, forgot to change it when I was copying it from your code. I think Lalit Sachdeva's answer is a better explanation tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1: 
Yes in the second case you are trying to define it again.
To define an app use:

```
angular.module('myApp', [..list of dependancies...]);
```

Now if you want to define controllers on the previous module use

```
angular.module('myApp').controller();
```

Now comes injecting your 3 dependancies, move them to the top where you have defined your app.

Ans 2: You will have to inject angularMoment to you app and moment to your controller.

The best way to handle dependancy injection in angular is to use $inject. for example you controller will look something like

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['moment','$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'myFactory', 'mySecondService']
function myController(moment, $scope, $http, $rootScope, myFactory, mySecondService){
    //your controller code.
}
```

or else you can try the following as well

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController',['moment','$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'myFactory', 'mySecondService', function myController(moment, $scope, $http, $rootScope, myFactory, mySecondService){
    //your controller code.
}]);
```

The following will also work but not recommended;

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController',function myController(moment, $scope, $http, $rootScope, myFactory, mySecondService){
        //your controller code.
    });
```